# Continuous Integration with Visual Studio Online and a multiple solution project

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have an MVC Web App that I am trying to get set up with continuous integration on Azure and Visual Studio Online. Basically, the solution has 4 projects within, 3 of which go to supporting the 1 Web App. The problem is, when I set up continuous deployment on Azure, it builds the entire solution and doesn't know which project I want for the root URL.

When I download the drop folder that is produced by the compilation it looks like this.

- drop/lots of dlls including the dll of my web app.
- drop/_PublishedWebsites
- drop/_PublishedWebsites/MyWebApp (including its bin, content, fonts etc)
- drop/_PublishedWebsites/MyWebApp_Package

and some other folders as well.

How can I configure the continuous deployment to put my Web App at the root of the website??

Thanks

Comment: Looks like these links have some information: [link1](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/95f161f6-9370-43ad-9ac5-714f8978cc5e/continuous-integration-deploying-wrong-project-from-solution?forum=azuregit) [link2](http://peter.orneholm.com/post/84647111808/deploy-to-multiple-azure-websites-with-visual-studio). Trying them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the dumb solution is to rename your "main" project to be the alphabetically first project in the solution. Microsoft suggests this, or having only one project per solution. Either way, this is the most reliable and simple way to get the desired effect.